# .htaccess rewrite rule to send data to PHP script without revealing location via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope the question didn't confuse you firstly. I'm very picky on security and do not want to have ANY PHP files anywhere in the public_html folder, but on the private area usually before this directory "../public_html". Here's a quick example of my needs, and do believe .htaccess will rescue me (or one of you guys!) with a solution. Inside JS I get data I want to send to PHP. I'm not going to write all the JS code but you'll understand surely. The JS file is located here: c://wamp64/public_html/assets/js/send_ajax.js and index /public_html/index.php

```
var username = helloWorlder;

/* and all the onreadystate change content here */

xmlhttp.open("POST", "this_is_the_problem_file_name.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("u=" + username);
```

You see the file I'm POSTing to, I want to have a rewrite condition so it can point to this example C://wamp64/private_area/php/this_file.php. I don't want to do this in the JS script ../../../private_area/this_file.php because that will be TOO much revealing a sensitive directory. To clarify the index page, and of course JS file is public. The PHP file isn't. Surely there's a way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here APIs come in to play

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess and javascript will only be able to communicate with what is publicly accessible by the browser.  What you will probably want is an intermediary controller.  You can set up a snippet in MODX that loads your hidden PHP files, set up a blank page that calls that snippet, then post your requests to that page and read the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a request that gets processed by a PHP program unless you give that PHP program a URL.

The easiest way to do that is to put the PHP program under the server root.

You *could* use `alias` or mod_rewrite to keep the file elsewhere, but that is largely pointless.

The only benefit that gives you is that in the unlikely event of something going wrong with your server configuration which might leak the source code of the PHP program, then it will likely go sufficiently wrong to break access to it entirely.

You can get the same benefits, without the complexity, by putting the *sensitive* **parts** of the program outside the server root and then `include()`ing them.